# Get a python slice to reverse the order of only part of a string( Swapping consecutive characters in a string )?

Tags: python

Given the word "coral", I need it to give me reversals of each letter pair. For example:

```
ocral
croal
coarl
corla
```

What I've got:

```
string  = raw_input("Enter a word:")
char_values = len(string) #length of string
char_values = int(char_values) #converts to number
print "DELETIONS:"
for word_value in range(char_values): 
print string[:word_value] + string[word_value+1:] #deletion pattern
print "TRANSPOSITIONS:"
for x in range(char_values):
print string[:x:-1]+string[x+2:] #shift pattern
```

I'm throwing out guesses in my last line. My result here was `laroral laral lal l`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

wrd = raw_input('Enter a word: ')

for i in range(len(wrd) - 1):
    print wrd[0:i] + wrd[i+1] + wrd[i] + wrd[i+2:]
```

Output:

```
paul@local:~/Documents/src/sandbox$ ./rev.py
Enter a word: coral
ocral
croal
coarl
corla
paul@local:~/Documents/src/sandbox$
```

Comment: Nice answer, Paul, apart from the use of `str` as a variable name... My variant: `word[0:i] + word[i:i+2][::-1] + word[i+2:]` but I _guess_ it's slightly less efficient than yours.

Comment: No worries, Paul. FWIW, I just did a quick timeit.py test. My expression takes around 10% longer than yours.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping the characters

```
string  = "apple"
char_values = len(string) #length of string
char_values = int(char_values) #converts to number
index  = 0
for word_value in range(char_values): 
    firstcharacter = string[word_value]
    others = string[:word_value] + string[word_value+1:]
    if index+1 < char_values:
        nextCharacter = string[index+1]
        print others[:index] + nextCharacter + firstcharacter+ others[index+1:]
    index = index +1
```

Output:

```
ocral
croal
coarl
corla
```

Comment: `nextCharacter = string[index+1]` will give you an `IndexError` on the last iteration, and `index = string.index(firstcharacter)` won't work well with a word with repeated characters, like `'apple'`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Sorry I didn't notice those two cases. And now I some how have solved both of the issues. Please have a look. :-) I know it's unnecessarily complex though

Comment: Yes, it is a bit complex, Nabin. And your variable names are a bit confusing, since `string` is a standard module and `index` is a method of built-in sequence types. `char_values = int(char_values)` is redundant because `len(string)` is already an int (but I realise that you just copied that from the question). And in Python, you don't need to store the length of such sequence types, since it's already stored as an attribute of the object. You save `firstcharacter`, but you only use it once. OTOH, you compute `index+1` 4 times per loop.

Comment: Once you remove the unnecessary assignments and tests, and improve the names, your code looks like this: `word = "apple"`
`for i in range(len(word) - 1): others = word[:i] + word[i+1:]; print others[:i] + word[i+1] + word[i] + others[i+1:]` which makes it fairly similar to that of @PaulGriffiths.